# Push Function (Adding new node to top of list) C++

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, push, nodes

I am trying to figure out how to create a function that adds a new node to the top of a stack while given:

```
// a structure for a node
struct node {
int key;
node * next;
};

// a structure for a stack
struct stack {
node * top;
node * bottom;
};

// and the function declaration
void push(stack & s, int key)
```

It is supposed to work for an empty stack and a stack of more than 1 node.

I am having a really hard time understanding how the pointers to structures work and how to add and remove to them, so any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a stack implemented with a singly linked list. One of the best ways to understand a linked list is to draw the sucker out on a piece of paper and watch how the nodes need to interconnect to make a meaningful list. Once you can visualize what must happen, the rest becomes a lot easier.

Comment: use list container of c++ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Answer (score 0):

s is a pointer to stack, and have two values ,i.e 'bottom' and 'top', top is the property of stack, but bottom should be start pointer of stack(which is in form of linked list)

```
void push(stack *s, int key)
{
   struct node newNode;
   newNode.key = key;
   newNode.next = NULL;

   if(s->top == NULL)
   {
       s->top =&newNode;
       s->bottom =&newNode;
   }
   else{
   //Assigning new node to top
   s->top->next = &newNode;

   //pointing top to new node
   s->top = &newNode;
   }
}
```

check it out.